# How to fix Jupyter notebook dependancies? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am running EMR cluster(AWS) but I do not understand how notebook imports packages. I am running PySpark kernel.

```
import boto3
No module named 'boto3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

print (sys.version) shows

```
3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
```

print(sys.executable) shows

```
/tmp/1594625399736-0/bin/python
```

I have both Conda and pip3 install of boto3.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using pyspark? If yes, then you need to install the packages in the spark context. Refer to this AWS document: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/

similarly install any dependency packages if you see module not found error on import. Make sure the versions are compatible.

Answer (score -1):

sc.list_packages()

```
Package                    Version
-------------------------- -------
beautifulsoup4             4.9.0  
boto                       2.49.0 
cycler                     0.10.0 
jmespath                   0.9.5  
kiwisolver                 1.2.0  
lxml                       4.5.0  
matplotlib                 3.2.2  
mysqlclient                1.4.2  
nltk                       3.4.5  
nose                       1.3.4  
numpy                      1.19.0 
pandas                     1.0.5  
pip                        9.0.1  
py-dateutil                2.2    
py4j                       0.10.9 
pyparsing                  2.4.7  
pyspark                    3.0.0  
python-dateutil            2.8.1  
python37-sagemaker-pyspark 1.3.0  
pytz                       2020.1 
PyYAML                     5.3.1  
setuptools                 28.8.0 
six                        1.15.0 
soupsieve                  1.9.5  
wheel                      0.29.0 
windmill                   1.6
```

I have boto.

Comment: you have boto not boto3

Answer (score -1):

sc.install_pypi_package("boto3")

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.